# How can I get the TaskId of a Fargate ecs Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Similar to this question [How to get Task ID from within ECS container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819809/how-to-get-task-id-from-within-ecs-container) but I want to get the `TaskId` for my `Fargate` task. How can you do this? Like others I want this for logging information.

I'm running a Spring App with ELK stack for logging and would like if possible to include the `TaskId` in the logs if possible.

**Edit**
I actually never got this to work by the way, here is my code:

```
    private String getTaskIdInternal() {

        String url = System.getenv("ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4") + "/task";

        logger.info("Getting ecsMetaDataURL={}", url);

        if (url == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4 env variable not defined");
        }

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonNode.class);

        logger.info("ecsMetaData={}", response);

        JsonNode map = response.getBody();

        String taskArn = map.get("TaskARN").asText();
        String[] splitTaskArn = taskArn.split("/");
        String taskId =  splitTaskArn[splitTaskArn.length - 1];
        logger.info("ecsTaskId={}", taskId);
        return taskId;
    }
```

But I always get this stack trace:

```
Could not get the taskId from ECS. exception=org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:325)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to get the task id in Fargate for ECS you make use of [metadata endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html).

Assuming you're using version `1.4.0` of Fargate you can get this via a http request to `${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}/task`.

An example response from this endpoint is below

```
{
    "Cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:&ExampleAWSAccountNo1;:cluster/default",
    "TaskARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:&ExampleAWSAccountNo1;:task/default/febee046097849aba589d4435207c04a",
    "Family": "query-metadata",
    "Revision": "7",
    "DesiredStatus": "RUNNING",
    "KnownStatus": "RUNNING",
    "Limits": {
        "CPU": 0.25,
        "Memory": 512
    },
    "PullStartedAt": "2020-03-26T22:25:40.420726088Z",
    "PullStoppedAt": "2020-03-26T22:26:22.235177616Z",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
    "Containers": [
        {
            "DockerId": "febee046097849aba589d4435207c04aquery-metadata",
            "Name": "query-metadata",
            "DockerName": "query-metadata",
            "Image": "mreferre/eksutils",
            "ImageID": "sha256:1b146e73f801617610dcb00441c6423e7c85a7583dd4a65ed1be03cb0e123311",
            "Labels": {
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:&ExampleAWSAccountNo1;:cluster/default",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name": "query-metadata",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:&ExampleAWSAccountNo1;:task/default/febee046097849aba589d4435207c04a",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family": "query-metadata",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version": "7"
            },
            "DesiredStatus": "RUNNING",
            "KnownStatus": "RUNNING",
            "Limits": {
                "CPU": 2
            },
            "CreatedAt": "2020-03-26T22:26:24.534553758Z",
            "StartedAt": "2020-03-26T22:26:24.534553758Z",
            "Type": "NORMAL",
            "Networks": [
                {
                    "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
                    "IPv4Addresses": [
                        "10.0.0.108"
                    ],
                    "AttachmentIndex": 0,
                    "IPv4SubnetCIDRBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "MACAddress": "0a:62:17:7a:36:68",
                    "DomainNameServers": [
                        "10.0.0.2"
                    ],
                    "DomainNameSearchList": [
                        "us-west-2.compute.internal"
                    ],
                    "PrivateDNSName": "ip-10-0-0-108.us-west-2.compute.internal",
                    "SubnetGatewayIpv4Address": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see you would need to parse the `TaskARN` to get the TaskID (it is the last part of the ARN if you split by "/".

Amazon do specify the following in the documentation that should be noted.

> For tasks using the Fargate launch type and platform versions prior to 1.4.0, the task metadata version 3 and 2 endpoint are supported. For more information, see [Task Metadata Endpoint version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3.html) or [Task Metadata Endpoint version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v2.html).

Comment: I would like to see how the http request looks like in this case. I am trying to get the value for ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4} and not sure how I get it for a fargate container

Comment: Hi @VijayakumarChava, Did you find the http request format you asked for above?

Comment: `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4` is an environment variable. You have multiple ways you can access env variables. For me, the value looks something like this: `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4="http://<ip>/v4/62sdf34fsdfsdf4a4dsdf36fc2104sdfg56-143832484`

Answer (score 0):

The link in the accepted answer is for EC2 launch type. The direct doc link for Fargate is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html. The json content seems to be pretty much the same though.

Comment: See code, I actually never got this to work, always get 403

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

> aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --service $SERVICE_NAME
> --query "taskArns" --output text

Bash script will make you easier as you don't have to define the defined variables everytime.

```
#!/bin/bash

export AWS_PROFILE=$AWS_PROFILE
CLUSTER_NAME=$CLUSTER_NAME
SERVICE_NAME=$SERVICE_NAME
CONTAINER_NAME=$CONTAINER_NAME

# Get a list of task ARNs
TASK_ARNS=($(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --service $SERVICE_NAME --query "taskArns" --output text))

# Check if there are tasks running
if [ ${#TASK_ARNS[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No tasks running."
  exit 1
fi

# Assume the first task in the list, you may modify this based on your logic
TASK_ID=${TASK_ARNS[0]}

# Execute command on the selected task
aws ecs execute-command --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
    --task $TASK_ID \
    --container $CONTAINER_NAME \
    --interactive \
    --command "/bin/sh"
```